# Java EE WebSockets in Glassfish possible "zombie" connection

Tags: java, websocket, duplicates, glassfish, connection

I am learning Java API for WebSockets and I have a question.
Every time I connect to the endpoint, the app creates 2 connections and the first one throws this exception:

```
Info:   websocketbot was successfully deployed in 3,174 milliseconds.
Info:   (@OnOpen method) Connection opened.
Info:   (@OnOpen method) Opened connections: 1
Warning:   Already set read listener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already set read listener
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.setReadListener(InputBuffer.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.setReadListener(CoyoteInputStream.java:312)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusHttpUpgradeHandler.init(TyrusHttpUpgradeHandler.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:413)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Info:   Connection opened.
Info:   Opened connections: 2
```

My Endpoint class:

```
package pckg;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/echo")
public class TestEndpoint {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("TestEndpoint");

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "(@OnOpen method) Connection opened.");
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "(@OnOpen method) Opened connections:" 
                + session.getOpenSessions().size());
    }

    @OnClose
    public void close(Session session) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "(@OnClose method) Connection closed.");
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "(@OnClose method) Opened connections:" 
                + session.getOpenSessions().size());
    }
}
```

When I close the connection (eg. close the browser) only one session instance is closed.

When I implemented @OnMessage method to receive messages and a method to send a message I receive every message twice.

What I want to ask is if this is supposed to happen. I am using NetBeans and GlassFish server with which I had problems in the past.

PS: I also tried an example application from official Oracle tutorial called "websocketbot" (a chat implementation). Its messages also get duplicated even though they clearly shouldn't. I also had to add some code to make it work 100%.

**EDIT:** The problem was indeed with GlassFish. It works OK on WildFly server.

Comment: Do you open the connection in javascript?

Comment: Can you test with [Payara Server](http://www.payara.fish) too? It's derived from GlassFish and if it works in Payara Server it's very probable that it's a bug in GlassFish.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue after turning on the access logs for glassfish. This seems like a bug in glassfish.

https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/70